# How can the difference between surface energy and electrostatic repulsion be calculated in electroplating?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, bond, metal, surface-chemistry

When metals are electroplated unto surfaces, there are a myriad of forces at play. To set a clear example, if one were to electroplate a magnet with a diamagnetic metal such as bismuth, there will be a certain amount of repulsion from the substrate from the surface. Hence, how could one check how much distance there will be from the applied metal to the surface?

Comment: There will not be any distance: either electroplating happens or does not, resulting in a  non-adherent outcome.

Comment: The diamagnetic force is relatively weak. Not sure what happens on long term, but it should stick to the surface at least after the electroplating. For example, a fridge magnet will easily attract a paper clip, but you won't feel the repulsion if you bring a gold coin near it.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear so I don't know why there are so many close votes.

Comment: Hope I could know was well, Maiti